# How to script value in Shader so it changes over time?

Tags: scripting, shaders, drivers

I need this number to change in a given range over time. I thought that I could just write a driver to this value, but I did not find any random function that could solve my task.
[image]

Comment: Type _#frame_ into the box. This will make the value correspond with the (current) frame number. Use a math node (or multiple) afterwards to manipulate the range (ex Math node dividing by 25 - default number of frames is 250, so this would yield a range from 0-10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put “#frame” in the input. that sets up driver that uses frame number as value. math nodes can change result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Keyframes for this task. Even if you don't see a diamond icon for keyframing you are still able to add keyframes. Hover mouse cursor over the value slider and press <kbd>I</kbd>. This will add a keyframe that you can use for animating the value